# Finalisation in FORTRAN 2003

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran2003

According to [Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status) the **intel fortran** compiler version 14 should support finalisation defined in FORTRAN 2003 standard. I tried to use this feature with **ifort 14**, but observed strange behaviour. Following example should show this:

```
module mtypes
    implicit none

    type mytype
        integer, private :: nr
        contains

            final :: delete_mytype
            procedure :: print_mytype
    end type

    contains


!>      \brief Constructs a new mytype
!!      \return The created mytype
!>
        function init_mytype(number)
            type(mytype) :: init_mytype
            integer, intent(in) :: number
!            allocate(init_mytype)
            init_mytype = mytype(number)
            print *, 'init mytype', number
        end function

!>      \brief De-constructs a mytype object
!>
        subroutine delete_mytype(this)
            type(mytype) :: this   !< The mytype object that will be finalized
            print *, 'Deleted mytype!', this%nr
        end subroutine delete_mytype

!>      \brief Print something from mytype object
!>
        subroutine print_mytype(this)
            class(mytype) :: this   !< The mytype object that will print something
            print *, 'Print something from mytype!', this%nr
        end subroutine print_mytype


end module mtypes

program main

    use mtypes
    type(mytype) :: t1, t2

    call t1%print_mytype()
    call t2%print_mytype()

    t1 = mytype(1)
    call t1%print_mytype()
    t2 = init_mytype(2)
    call t2%print_mytype()

end program main
```

Within this complete example the `type mytype` is defined that only has one value `nr`. This type can be created using simple type constructor e.g. `mytype(1)` or the initialising function `init_mytype`. Also a subroutine `print_mytype` is defined that simply prints `mytype%nr` to stdout. Finally, the `final` routine `delete_mytype` should be used for finalisation, although in this example case it only prints some information to stdout.

This example gives following output:

```
 Print something from mytype!           0
 Print something from mytype!           0
 Deleted mytype!           0
 Print something from mytype!           1
 Deleted mytype!          -2
 init mytype           2
 Deleted mytype!           0
 Deleted mytype!           2
 Print something from mytype!           2
```

- Line 1: Ok, t1 initialised with default value 0
- Line 2: Ok, t2 initialised with default value 0
- Line 3: Ok, after assignment of new object `t1%mytype(1)` the old version is deleted
- Line 4: Ok, version with `nr = 1` is printed
- Line 5: Strange, where does a version with `nr=-2` come from?
- Line 6: Ok, version with `nr = 2` is initialised
- Line 7: Ok, after assignment of new object `t2 = init_mytype(2)` the old version is deleted
- Line 8: Strange, t2 is finalized before call of `t2%print_mytype()`
- Line 9: Strange, t2 is printed after finalisation

Is this strange behviour caused by some ifort bug or is this caused by wrong application of the finalization FORTRAN 2003 feature and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be better to set a default value in the type definition, `integer, private :: nr = 0`, than rely on the automatic initialization done by the compiler. That being said, as far as I know, ifort initializes all integers to zero by default so I'm not sure what causes these problems. In my machine, it prints zero on the 5th line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What appears strange is actually the result of the rules on finalization.  In Fortran 2008 4.5.6.3 ("When finalization occurs") the prompts for finalization are given.

Before coming to those, a word about initialization.  You say

> Line 1: Ok, t1 initialised with default value 0

The derived type component `nr` doesn't have default initialization, and there's no explicit initialization for `t1`, so your statement isn't true.  In fact, `t1%nr` is undefined at this point.  `0` just happens to be the result.  This is important, as we see later.

Your code, with comments about finalization:

```
t1 = mytype(1)          ! t1 finalized before assignment
call t1%print_mytype()
t2 = init_mytype(2)     ! t2 finalized before assignment, after function
                        ! init_mytype result finalized after assignment
call t2%print_mytype()
                        ! No finalization before END PROGRAM (4.5.6.4)
```

Your lines 8 and 9 unexpected behaviour are not strange.  In particular, `call t2%print_mytype()` occurs after the two finalization calls in the statement `t2=init_mytype(2)`.

Now, where does the finalization from line 5 come from?  And why `-2`?  Remember that there is no initialization?  `-2` is an allowed result if a finalization occurs for an entity without assignment.  Which entity is finalized?

Look in the function `init_mytype` returning a result of type `mytype`:

```
function init_mytype(number)
  type(mytype) :: init_mytype    ! No initialization of result
  integer, intent(in) :: number

  init_mytype = mytype(number)   ! Result finalized before assignment
  print *, 'init mytype', number
end function
```

To conclude, the following prompts occur in this program:

> - When an intrinsic assignment statement is executed, the variable is finalized after evaluation of expr and before the definition of the variable.
> - If an executable construct references a function, the result is finalized after execution of the innermost executable construct containing the reference.

As an aside, if you look at the draft Fortran 2008 standard (such as I did when I mistakenly copied the wrong prompt in an earlier revision of this answer) you may think: why aren't the results of the structure constructor finalized? This should happen twice: once directly in the program, and once indirectly through the call to `init_mytype`.  But we see no such effect.

Consider the interpretation request ["How many times are constructed values finalized?"](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-158r1.txt) and the [corrigendum](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1901-N1950/N1902.pdf).  Constructor results are considered to be not finalized, correcting a mistake in Fortran 2003.  This may be relevant, as you do ask about Fortran 2003 (although ifort clearly implements the new rules).

Comment: OK on line 5. Final question is on line 8. The object with nr = 2 in init_mytype is copied to t2 in main and afterwards finalized in init_mytype. t2 in main is not finalized, because it's the end of main. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: There are two objects with `nr=2`, yes, and it is indeed the result of `init_mytype` which is finalized (the other being `t2` after the assignment).  Nothing is finalized on reaching `END PROGRAM`.

Comment: "If image execution is terminated, .., by execution of a .. end-program-stmt , entities existing immediately prior to termination are not finalized."